# CakePHP models findFirst method issue

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm not familiar with CakePHP too close. Recently I've ran into problem using Model. I need to get exaclty one row from database, modify some columns values and save it back. Pretty simple, right?

What do I try to do:

```
$condition = array('some_id_column' => $another_models_id);
$model = $this->MyModel->findFirst($condition);
```

BUT i get `FALSE` in $model variable. At hte same time

```
$condition = array('some_id_column' => $another_models_id);
$model = $this->MyModel->findAll($condition);
```

returns array. Its structure is something like:

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'MyModel' =>
    array (
      'id' => '1',
      'some_id_column' => '123456',
      'some_field' => 'some text',
      ...
    ),
  ),
```

I'd go with `findAll` if it did not return an array of arrays, but array of models (in my case - of one model). What do I want to achieve:

```
$condition = array('some_id_column' => $another_models_id);
$model = $this->MyModel->findFirst($condition);
$model->some_field = 'some another text';
$model->save();
```

Could you help me out to understand how it's usually done in `CakePHP`?
I'd also like to hear why `findAll` finds row and `findFirst` fails to find it... It just does not make sense to me... They should work in almost the same way and use the same database APIs...

If I can not do what I want in CakePHP, would you write a receipt how it is usually done there ?

Comment: It might help to read the documentation. It will walk you through everything you need to know.

Comment: @cdburgess I did not know that. Thank you :) I will... maybe... most likely... sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no such method as `findFirst`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data).
You're probably looking for `find('first', array('conditions' => array(...)))`.

Comment: Ohh... Indeed I needed to look inside of CakePHP Model's code... I though `findFirst` is implemented by magic `__call` as well as `findAll`. Apparently findAll is implemented and magic `__call` only implements `findBy<field>` methods.